# Install Qt5.12 on travis-ci linux

Tags: qt, travis-ci, qt5.12

I'm seeing following error while trying to Install `Qt5.12` on `travis-ci` linux. Someone please help

```
$ ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.10.run
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3" since plugins are disabled in static builds
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: minimal, xcb.
```

Comment: add `services:
  - xvfb`, see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-services

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did tried adding services: xvfb, and see this below error. 

.travis_wait 60 ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.0.run
Still running (49 of 60): ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.0.run
The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been terminated.

Comment: The problem is that this is an installer that is waiting for the user to accept the conditions, press the next button, etc. It is not an automatic installer. If you want it to install Qt without a user interacting then I recommend using aqtinstall

Comment: I'm newbie to QT and I tried using aqtinstall but ended up with version 
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
I rather trying to install qt 5.12.0 and added following commands to my .travis.yml
- pip install aqtinstall
- aqt install --outputdir /home/travis/build/Qt 5.12.0 linux desktop

Please do let me know how to install version 5.12.0 on linux. Thank you and appreciate your prompt responces.

Comment: You have to update some environment variables since your CI has Qt installed which causes that conflict, see https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall#environment-variables

Comment: This didn't help either :(